# Collect Data from Google Result Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to have a stream: Say from google:
http://news.google.com/news/search?aq=f&pz=1&cf=all&ned=en_ke&hl=en&q=C#

I want to be able to give the Seach Parameter: In this instance C# or any other search parameter and then have the results shown in my page.

I am faced with a situation where I have to collect info from google and create an msword doc with it. I want to be able to automate the data collection and hopefully the word doc creation from the strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add output=rss onto the end of your feed, you can just read the data in XML format and write it out to your word file however you want e.g.

http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=en_ke&hl=en&q=C&cf=all**&output=rss**

Have a read up on the XmlTextReader as well if you're not sure how to read the RSS feed.

Comment: Lets assume I want to get all news on google with the tag SPACE SHUTTLE released today. 

How do I read that into string from a C# website?

Comment: You use the XmlTextReader object that I mentioned above, and pass the URL with your query in as part of that string i.e.

Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader (http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=en_ke&hl=en&q=SPACE+SHUTTLE&cf=all&output=rss)